# Emitting An Unlimited Amount of Particles

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles, particle-system

I am trying to make my particle system in Cocos2d-iPhone to have an unlimited amount of particles. This is the code I have so far.

```
//Create the particles
CCParticleExplosion *explosion = [CCParticleExplosion particleWithTotalParticles: PARTICLECOUNTER];
explosion.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
explosion.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:0.1f green:0.2f blue:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
explosion.life = 100.0f;
explosion.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
explosion.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
[self addChild:explosion z:0];
```

What should take the place of PARTICLECOUNTER?

Comment: a very high number? Keep in mind that anywhere between 500+ to 2500+ particles can easily kill your framerate.